# How to set custom timeout duration for captcha solving using puppeteer and recaptcha plugin

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, recaptcha, playwright, 2captcha

I'm using puppeteer with puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha plugin. I want to set a custom timeout for 2captcha solving but I'm having a hard time.
The method I use is:

```
await page.solveRecaptchas()
```

But I couldn't find anything timeout-related in the plugin documentation, I tried multilpe guess-kind of solutions `page.setDefaultTimeout(x)` , `page.solveRecaptchas({timeout: x})`  but none works.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: I can show you a playwright trick to solve google captchas on single click. I don't know about puppeteer though.  Let me know if you are interested in the playwright procedure .

Answer (score 0):

Don't use timeout with timer.
Instead check the [aria-checked] of the "checkbox" if this set to true, then continue.

```
const frame = page.frames().find(async (frame) => await frame.title() === 'reCAPTCHA')

// You can choose between these two methods below

// Try this lines below
const checkmark = await frame.waitForSelector('#recaptcha-anchor', {visible: true})
while (await frame.evaluateHandle((checkmark) => checkmark.getAttribute('aria-checked') !== 'true', checkmark)) {
    await page.waitForTimeout(100)
}

// Or simply this lines below
await frame.waitForFunction(() => {
    return document.querySelector('#recaptcha-anchor').getAttribute('aria-checked') === 'true'
}, {timeout: 0, polling: 100})

// Then you can check
// reCaptcha solved successfully
```